# Upgrade PostgreSQL 8.1 to 8.3 on Debian Lenny, but zend php still recognize pgsql as version 8.1

Tags: php, postgresql, zend-server-ce

The story goes like this:

1. I have Zend server CE PHP5.3 with all the modules available enabled running on Debian Etch.
2. I decided to upgrade Debian Etch to Lenny, then also upgraded PostgreSQL 8.1 to 8.3
3. Restored the database `mydatabase` --> $ psql `mydatabase` < schema_and_data.sql
4. Checked the web site that connects to a postgreSQL database and got this error.

   - Error: Failed to connect to database.
5. So I manually login to postgreSQL -> postgres@devserver:/$ psql mydatabase
6. Obviously postgreSQL is fine with `mydatabase` as my database
7. I checked phpinfo and PostgreSQL(libpq) Version : 8.1.1 (which was the previous version instead of the new 8.3)

I'm stuck at #6 at the moment.
Aside from doing the following that I think would fix it back to 'working condition':

1. Also downgrading postgreSQL 8.3 to 8.1 is not allowed as postgresSQL 8.1 is not supported on Lenny.
2. Setup my Debian box back to Etch and install zend/postgreSQL 8.1.

Any idea how to re-configure php-5.3-pgsql-zend on Lenny to recognize the new 8.3 version? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't restarted your web server or php-cgi process, try that.  They probably still have an old copy of libpq and/or the php pgsql stuff loaded.